# Symfony, Liip Imagine bundle not working on server in prod environment

Tags: symfony, production-environment, liipimaginebundle

I have a project where I keep my uploaded images in *src/My/Bundle/Resources/uploads/images/full* and use the twig filter `imagine_filter` to dynamically create thumbnails.

On my local machine it works flawlessly and so does on my server, but there only under the dev environment. When I delete the previously created thumbnails (leaving only the *full* directory), clear the prod cache and load any web page, the images are not created, their url always remains under *media/cache*, and the logger gives me the `request.ERROR`:

```
"No route found for "GET /uploads/images/avatar/354026c94b773b77ca945b4a6323e15c84102f6b.jpg"" at /<path>/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 1964 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for \"GET /uploads/images/avatar/354026c94b773b77ca945b4a6323e15c84102f6b.jpg\" at /<path>/app/cache/prod/classes.php:1964, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException:  at /<path>/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:1816
```

Some additional infos:

- I have symlinked *src/My/Bundle/Resources/uploads* to *web/uploads*
- my config is (`thumbnail_min` is a custom filter):

  `liip_imagine:
      loaders:
          default:
              filesystem:
                  data_root: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/images/full
      resolvers:
          default:
              web_path: 
                  web_root: %kernel.root_dir%/../web
                  cache_prefix: /uploads/images
      cache: default
      filter_sets:
          avatar:
              quality: 90
              filters:
                  thumbnail_min: { size: 50, mode: inset }
          ....
          full:
              quality: 100`
- permissions are always at least group rw (that's what is needed on the server)

Answer (score 0):

Just experienced a similar problem on my local machine, however still in dev environment.

For me, I was missing group writable permission on the default media/cache folder, which stayed empty after a liip:imagine:cache:remove and page reload. Thus images were linking to empty folder.

To fix, I first made sure that Group was set to Apache's _www (mac) / www-data (linux), e.g.

- sudo chgrp -R www-data web/media/cache

Then made sure the folder was set to readable, writable and executable, e.g.

- sudo chmod -R g+rwx web/media/cache

Hope this helps...

Comment: unfortunately not, the problem only exists when a lot of images are requested at once, if they are accessed in smaller numbers it doesn't happen, so I'm sure it isn't the permission (as I said in the question..)

Comment: did u find a solution? i am stuck with the same problem